# Can Assets/Resoures be shared between iOS + Droid projects?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I have a Xamarin based Visual Studio 2015 project that has the following structure.

MyApp (Portable)
MyApp.Droid
MyApp.iOS

Currently I include assets / resources in the MyApp.Droid project **and** the MyApp.iOS project.

So for example `myhtml.html` is **duplicated** as both MyApp.Droid/Asserts/myhtml.html and MyApp.iOS/Resources/myhtml.html

Are there any ways I can avoid this duplication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using Xamarin Forms, yes, you can use .net resource files.

You can create a folder in the portable project, add there the content files and set the Compilation Action to Embedded Resource for all of those, then you can use the .net provided mechanism to acces the resources, per example (in this example I assume the code is being executed in a class contained in the portable project and the files are stored in a folder called ResourceFiles):

```
var htmlFile = this.GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("MyNamespace.ResourceFiles.myhtml.html");
```

In this way you have the stream with the file's content.

Also, as a hint, you can load these files from XAML using a custom markup extension, per example, here is a markup extension to load images from .net resources:

```
[ContentProperty ("Source")]
public class ImageResourceExtension : IMarkupExtension
{
    public string Source { get; set; }

    public object ProvideValue (IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        if (Source == null)
            return null;

        var imageSource = new StreamImageSource { Stream = async (ct) => this.GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(Source) }; 

        return imageSource;
    }
}
```

Then, to use this extension in XAML you will do (local is the XAML namespace definition of your own namespace):

```
<Image Source="{local:ImageResource MyNamespace.ResourceFiles.MyImage.png}" />
```